# Square of a directed graph $G=\left< V, E\right>$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, graph-traversal

I have this question from CLRS book please.

**Question**: The square of a directed graph  $G=\left< V, E\right>$ is the graph  $G=\left< V, E^2\right>$ such that $(u,w) \in E^2 $ iff  for some $v \in V$, both $(u,v) \in E$  and  $(v,w) \in E$. That is $G$ contains a path with **EXACTLY two edges** between $u$ and $w$. Describe efficient algorithms for computing $G^2$ from $G$ for both the adjacency list and adjacency-matrix representations of $G$. Analyze the running times of your algorithms.

**Attempt**:

What we did here is that w loop through all vertices $v$ of $G$ and then add another nested loop to loop through all $u$ adjacent to $v$ and finally another loop of all vertices $w$ in $G$ that are adjacent to $u$ and add them to $E^2$.

[image]

**Problem**:

I will analyze only adjacency list representation please. Running time as I see it is $O(V+V\times E \times E)= (V+VE^2)$, but what I got is as follows:

1. We construct the edges in time $O(VE)$? My question here please: We have $O(VE)$ because we have $V$ vertices and $E=\Sigma_v(deg(v)) = 2m = E$ please?
2. After edges satisfying $E^2$ property is constructed, in $O(VE)$, we remove duplicates in time $O(V+ E\times E) = O(V+ E\times V)$, so total time is  which $O(VE) + O(V+ E\times V)$. My question here please: why please $O(V+ E\times E) = O(V+ E\times V)$?

Comment: The second step of your time analysis is not clear. For example, how $O(V+E \cdot E) = O(V + E \cdot V)$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami. I don't know actually. The analysis I did got me  $O(V+VE^2)$, but the one I found online in the second step says it's $O(EV)+O(V+EV)$

Comment: Once you visit a node $w$, you can mark it visited so that you do not add it again in the adjacency list of $u$. In this way, you can avoid adding duplicates in the first step of your algorithm. Then, you do not require step 2.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami. Thanks. Can you please analyze running time of algorithm above? Again, the analysis I did got me $O(VE^2)$ but the analysis I found says it's $O(VE)$ although we have 3 nested loops: first for vertices and second and third for edges, so why we don't get $O(VE^2)$, but $O(VE)$?

Comment: Total number of edges traversed in nested loop 1 and 2 are at most E. Do you see it?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami. Oh! Thanks. Total edges in case we multigraph might be larger than $E$, so we do delete multiple edges before and that will guarantee that we have a total of $E$ edges please?

Comment: Yeah, you can say that.